# Eclipse C++ environment quiestion: Conditionally launching an executable

Tags: c++, eclipse, build, eclipse-cdt

I recently started to putter around with C++ projects in Eclipse. It's definitely a tad trickier than working with Java but I managed to figure out most things.

However, at least one issue is escaping my ability to resolve. I wanted Eclipse to not bother trying to run an executable if a clean build failed.

Currently it pops up an annoying dialog box if the build fails because it appears to be blindly trying to launch. At least my clean build prevents the IDE from launching a stale executable but it would be nice to also get rid of the dialog box.

Any tips out there from Eclipse experts?